# Is there a result that the density function for $\chi^{2}$ must be related to the standard normal density?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose we have a random variable $X$ with the property that $-X = X$ (in distribution) and $X^{2} = \chi^{2}(1)$? I want to be able to conclude that $X \sim N(0,1)$.

The probability density function for the $\chi^{2}(1)$ is given by $f(x) = \frac{x^{-1/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x/2}$. Is there any result that says that a continuous distribution with a density of this form *has* to come from some kind of function of the standard normal distribution?

It's clear that if $Z \sim N(0,1)$, then $|Z|^{2}, (-Z)^{2},$ and $Z^{2}$ would all have a density function agreeing with the chi-square for $x \geq 0$. I could then easily rule out the case that $X = |Z|$ since it is not equal in distribution to $-X$ or $X$. But without a result relating the pdf with some function of the standard normal, there could be other distributions with such a density.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No general result here but the distribution of $X^2$ fully determines the distribution of $|X|$ since:

- The random variable $|X|$ is a function of $X^2$.
- If $X$ and $-X$ coincide in distribution then the distribution of $|X|$ fully determines the distribution of $X$ since the latter is the distribution of $S\cdot|X|$ where $S=\pm1$ is symmetric Bernoulli and independent of $|X|$.

In formulas, if the density of $Y=X^2$ is $f_Y$ then the density $f_X$ of $X$ symmetric is $$f_X(x)=|x|\cdot f_Y(x^2).$$
If one does not assume that $X$ is symmetric, one only knows that $$f_X(x)+f_X(-x)=2\cdot|x|\cdot f_Y(x^2),$$ hence, for every $x$, $$f_X(x)=\theta(x)\cdot|x|\cdot f_Y(x^2),$$ where $\theta$ can be any nonnegative function defined on the real line such that, for every $x$, $$\theta(x)+\theta(-x)=2.$$

Comment: Thanks. Is that relation between the density functions just a routine obtained from changing variables, or does the presence of the $|x|$ connect to what you said about the relation between all these distributions?

Comment: One cannot deduce the density of $X$ from the density of $Y=X^2$ alone (for example, $X$ and $|X|$ correspond to the same $Y$) but if one adds that $X$ must be symmetric then $X=S\sqrt{Y}$ with $(S,Y)$ independent, $S$ symmetric Bernoulli, hence the general identity $f_Y(y)=(f_X(\sqrt{y})+f_X(-\sqrt{y}))/(2\sqrt{y})$ yields the reverse relation in my post since $f_X(x)=f_X(-x)$.